# Replace general term of function series with sum of even and odd one

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functions, power-series

Under what conditions can I rewrite the general term of a function series as the sum of a term  and the following one?

Like in the following example, the general term was replaced with one with even exponent $2k$ and another one with the folloing (odd) number as exponent $2k+1$.

$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}{\ln\left(1+\frac{(-1)^n}{n}\right)} =\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left[{\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{2k} \right)} + \ln\left(1 - \frac{1}{2k+1}\right) \right]$$

Does the previous equality hold in any case or under some conditions? In particular must I know in advance that the series $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}{\ln\left(1+\frac{(-1)^n}{n}\right)}$ is **absolutely** convergent before writing that equality?

Comment: You can write your equality but we cannot separate in two sums.

Comment: In your expression you haven't changed the order of summation, so you're fine. You need absolute convergence (and recall that is equivalent to unconditional convergence) in order to break it into two series. In your example this fails because $ln(1 + 1/n) = -1/n +O(1/n^2)$ and so the series of absolute terms diverges.

Comment: @ScottBurns Thanks for the answer! May I ask why the condition to split it in two series is **absolute** convergence? Apparently the implication $$\sum_{n\geq 0} (f_n(x)+g_n(x)) \text{ converges absolutely} \\
\implies\sum_{n\geq 0} f_n(x) \text{ converges and } \sum_{n\geq 0} g_n(x) \text{ converges}$$
does not hold so I do not explain it to myself in terms of the fact that absolute convergence is necessary for the convergence of the two series in to which the original serie is split. So why is absolute convergence requested?

Comment: No problem. Check your text book and you should find a theorem that states that absolute convergence implies unconditional convergence. Unconditional convergence is defined to say that the order of summation does not affect the outcome. This is looking at each $f_n$ and each $g_n$ as elements of the sequence. It's not valid to break up terms, even if they converge absolutely. The simplest example is
$$ 
\sum_{n \ge 0} (1-1) \ne \sum_{n \ge 0} 1 + \sum_{n \ge 0} -1
$$

Comment: I should add that if you break up terms so that the summands are absolutely convergent, then you're fine.